# Can you connect to web service using python, and no external modules?

Tags: python, web-services, powershell, soap, module

I connect to a web service using PowerShell with the following code:

```
$websvc = New-WebServiceProxy -uri http://myserver:9111/servname?wsdl
```

I can then run methods on the variable, eg:

```
$websvc.getProp()
```

I want to do this using python in a Unix environment, but I can't seem to find a method without using external modules (ex: SOAPpy, ZSI, SUDS, etc.). I can't install any of the python modules in the Unix environment, so i wanted to try using the standard library of modules. Is there any way to do this with Python 2.6 and no external modules? Also, I'm assuming this is a SOAP service; but I haven't discussed with the developers, so I can't be 100% certain.

Comment: You can install Python modules locally (i.e., without root privileges).

Answer (score 2):

(a) Yes python comes with everything to do this *reasonably* straightforwardly, albeit rather more awkwardly than if you just installed a library.

(b) You don't need to be root to install modules. The most convenient way to do this is with `virtualenv` and `pip`.

Comment: I'll have to delve deeper into the documentation to find how to do this, but I would still prefer to use only python.

Comment: The modules you install will be only python.